# Leave Macrolite Ring Adapter 67 on 100mm macro?

Tags: flash, lens-adapter, vignetting

I've just bought a MR-14 EX II ring flash and the necessary ring adapter for my 100mm 2.8L macro lens. I'm now wondering if there is any reason why I shouldn't leave the adapter on my lens permanently - it seems more practical to just leave it there.

I guess I'll need a new lens cap (I've just tested this - a 58mm cap fits perfectly). I'm not using any other filters, and mounting/dismounting the hood isn't affected by the ring adapter.

Or would I run into vignetting problems in some situations? (I've taken a few test snapshots at f2.8/focus at infinity, and I can't really tell if there's a difference, so that should mean it's OK, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do the same thing with my Canon 100mm macro lens and I can't see any difference whatsoever in the photos, since the adapter is built NOT to cause any vignetting.

In the end, if you are happy with the  results and don't notice anything wrong with them, why not leave it on? Mechanically, there's nothing that say you shouldn't do it.